# onnx runtime without ML.NET

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version, onnx, ml.net, onnxruntime

I am trying to run an ONNX inference session in c# in a system that can only run .net framework 4.8.Unfortunetely,framework 4.8 can not run ML.NET and upgrading is not an option. Are there any tricks or workaround that I can get ONNX runtime to work? I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Inference with C# section of the ONNX Runtime docs](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/csharp/). That should have the info you need to inference with C# outside of ML.NET